# Makefile for compiling .idls

Tags: c++, makefile, corba, idl

I'm writing my first Makefile to compile some CORBA `.idl` definitions for use as part of a larger system. I use omniORB's `omniidl` program which takes `file.idl` and creates `file.hh` and a `fileSK.cc`. Each `.idl` has no dependencies and is created with the command `omniidl -bcxx file.idl`.

From reading the GNU Make tutorial it seems like Pattern Rules will do exactly what I need. The target for `.idl` conversion is inspired by the `bison` example in [Section 10.5.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Examples) of the GNU manual. My main question is how do I actually trigger these rules? I've tried putting in an all target and introducing the dependency on the `.idl`s but to no avail.

```
    OMNIIDL := omniidl 
    DEPENDFLAGS := -g 
    CXX := g++
    CXXFLAGS := $(DEPENDFLAGS) -Wall -Werror -ansi

    %.o : %.cc
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

    %.hh %SK.cc : %.idl
        $(OMNIIDL) -bcxx $<

    all : $(wildcard *.idl)
```

In a related note, where should auto-generated code normally be placed? I intend to copy the compiled `.o` files into my project's `/lib` or `/include` directory but should the `.hh` and `.cc` files be left in the `src` folder or placed elsewhere to ease the cleaning process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies of your `all` target should be a list of object files, instead of the list of idl files. Something like this:

```
all: $(patsubst %.idl, %SK.o, $(wildcard *.idl))
```

(For clarity, you could also introduce a variable to hold the list of idl files, and then use a substitution reference to get the list of object files:

```
IDLS := $(wildcard *.idl)

all: $(IDLS:%.idl=%SK.o)
```

)